# gnu parallel with bash array

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, bash-array

I trying to run command recon-all with GNU parallel [freesurfer preproc](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/recon-all) i have a bash array of list of patients to run 8 patents simultaneously:

```
root@4d8896dfec6c:/tmp# echo ${ids[@]}
G001 G002 G003 G004 G005 G006 G007 G008
```

and try to run with command:

```
echo ${ids[@]} | parallel --jobs 28 recon-all -s {.} -all -qcache
```

it doesn't work because i suppose i need to have bash array in ls representation, smth like:

```
ls ${ids[@]} | parallel --jobs 28 recon-all -s {.} -all -qcache
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `parallel` wants the input to be separated by newlines but when you use `echo` it is separated by spaces.  In order to print some words separated by newlines you can try one of these

```
echo one two three | tr ' ' '\n'    # in case your input can not be controlled by you
printf '%s\n' one two three         # if you can control the words eg if you have an array
```

So you should probably do it like this:

```
printf '%s\n' "${ids[@]}" | parallel --jobs 28 recon-all -s {.} -all -qcache
```

<sub>Remember to quote your array substitutions and variables in general in order to prevent accidental word splitting and other side effects if your values contain special characters.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

If the ids fits on a single command line:

```
parallel --jobs 28 recon-all -s {.} -all -qcache ::: "${ids[@]}"
```

Else like Lucas suggests:

```
printf %s\\n "${ids[@]}" | parallel --jobs 28 recon-all -s {.} -all -qcache
```